# Login and Session Management for Appgyver Supersonic

Tags: session, authentication, steroids, appgyver, supersonic

I just started using Appgyver's Platform: Supersonic and Composer. I have set my login screen and what it does is upon confirmation that the user is indeed a user, it redirects it to another page. I used supersonic.ui.initialView.dismiss() to achieve that.

Now I need to store data locally so that I can continuously access it for extending  functionality. Any idea, reference links or so on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `localStorage` on the phone. You can get/set/delete localStorage items easily.
[Here](http://docs.appgyver.com/supersonic/guides/architecture/communication/#localstorage) is a doc on Appgyver.

Here is an example of storing latitude and longitude:

```
var coords = { 
    lat : 'some value',
    lon : 'some other value'
}
localStorage.setItem('NameOfApp_coords', JSON.stringify(coords));
```

And getting the item from localStorage:

```
var coords = localStorage.getItem('NameOfApp_coords');
if(typeof coords !== undefined) {
    parsedCoords = JSON.parse(coords);
}
```

You can remove items as well:

```
localStorage.removeItem('NameOfApp_coords');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am looking at something more specific. Let me explain.

What I wish to do here is that post storing data, I would like to use this to validate from my server every time user logs in and then authenticate them.

any way to do that?

Comment: Our API returns a token specific to a user. That gets stored with the user id in `localStorage`. When the user logs in, this information is stored upon success. When they open the app and this information already exists, we know they are an authenticated user.

Comment: But the thing is, I want the server to know that too. The thing is that I have an existing web app which I need to connect to my  mobile app now. My server will continuosly check for authentication.

I suppose my only  option is that I create an API from scratch for everything and then use localstorage for authentication to API access. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. I don't see another way based on what I've seen so far.